# How to delay $watch execution in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which has two way data binding. The data is processed when $watch is executed. At the load time only the watches get called. There are two watches, on different variables, calling exactly the same function. I want only second watch should be executed initially. Find below the abstract I have created to explain the scenario.

I tried removing the watches and used the $scope.options.refresh from MainCtrl, but even if it's dual binding, the object is not the same. It eventually syncs but initially, options does not have the method refresh.
Please what would be the best I can implement in this case. I will be needing this in my future directives as well. Thanks.

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

.directive('dataList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><input ng-model="things.name" type="text" /></div>',
    scope: {
      things:'=',
      opts: "="
    }, 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    },
    controller:function($scope){
      $scope.opts.refresh = function(){
        //process Data 
        // filterData();
        // groupData;
        // sortData
      }

      $scope.$watch('things', function(){
        $scope.opts.refresh();
      });


      $scope.$watch('opts', function(){
        $scope.opts.refresh();
      })  

    }
  };
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { //This is parent controller
  $scope.data = {
    name: "World"
  };

  //This invokes the watch in directive first time.
  $scope.opts={
    filters:{  'column2':'valueToFilter'},
    groupBy:'column1',
    orderBy:''
  }

  $scope.loadMoreData = function(){
    //data is changed from some service
    //$scope.data = newResponse;
    // This invokes the watch in directive first time
  }

  //For loading data initially.
  $scope.loadMoreData();
});


//Html is as follows
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Hello {{data.name}}!</p>
        <data-list things="data"></data-list>

        <button ng-click="loadMoreData()">Load More</button>
      </body>
```

Comment: try working with the arguments of `$watch` callback `newValue,oldValue` ... or use a flag variable

Comment: have you tried to use `$timeout` ?

Comment: maybe place your controller before your directive?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @Paulo, $timeout will delay the things unnecessarily. The processing includes filtering , grouping and sorting of the data. If I do not use $timeout, it would be completed till the time everything is loaded. Or it will start after angularjs finishes the rendering all the directives, etc.

Comment: @charlietfl, can you suggest some code?

Comment: Try ... `$scope.$watch('things', function(newValue, oldValue){ if(newValue){ $scope.opts.refresh();})`